# Searching For Image - Instagram API

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, instagram

I'm working on an web based image search platform that uses Instagram. I've looked over the API and I noticed that there's are no ways to call any of the endpoints without the OAuth authentication. I don't want to make people sign in every time they want to search for something. I would like to make it function as a normal search box would.

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to circumvent this problem? I was thinking of automating the authentication of my own account and storing the token... allowing users to search without needing to login. I'm not to sure how to accomplish this.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Authentication API documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) you could just use your own token for each request but there are rate limits for a token and you will have to handle token expiration.

The BIG downside, and major security concern, to using your own account for access is that you are essentially giving access to your account when requests are submitted.

For a [media call](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) you just use your token

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}?access_token=<YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN-HERE>
```

Comment: Yes, the rate limit is a very limiting factor. How could I get around it? Also what if the access token expires and I need to re-authenticate?

Comment: Would creating multiple accounts and storing / rotating through the tokens work?

Comment: You could come up with some home-brew way of getting around having users login or you could... you know... just have users log in and then you only have to handle their token.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. You have been most helpful. Preferably I don't want to make users login - I want to keep it open to everyone with or without an account.